# React State does not update with axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on my first React App :-)
On my login page, I initialized isAdmin and IsLoggedIn and I want to update them when my axios request is OK.
But I get the following error :

> "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function"

So I tried useEffect but then I get

> "React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "handleSubmit" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function"

```
useEffect(() => {
  Api.post("/auth/login", loginFormData) //requête POST via Axios

    .then(function (response) {
      //Si Ok
      history.push("/forum");
      console.log(response);
      localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      localStorage.setItem("id", response.data.id);
      localStorage.setItem("isAdmin", response.data.isAdmin);
      setIsAdmin(response.data.isAdmin);
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
      console.log(isAdmin);
      console.log(isLoggedIn);
    })

    .catch(function (response) {
      // Si erreur
      console.log(response);
      alert("Password incorrect ou email inexistant dans la base de données");
    });
}, []);
```

I'm a bit lost here, thanks for your kind help and understanding !!
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yundps?file=src/App.js

```
    
import loginpic from "../../assets/login-image.png";
import '../../styles/style.css'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Api from '../Api'
import {
  useHistory,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";


function Login() {

        let history = useHistory();
        localStorage.clear();
        
        const [email, setEmail] = useState(""); //initialisation du state vide
        const [password, setPassword] = useState(""); //initialisation du state vide
        const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(""); //initialisation du state vide
        const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(""); //initialisation du state vide

        const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/.test(email)) { 

            let loginFormData = { 
                email : email, 
                password: password
            };
         
      
            console.log(loginFormData);

         
         Api.post('/auth/login', loginFormData) //requête POST via Axios

                .then(function (response) {  //Si Ok
                history.push("/forum")   
                console.log(response);
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                localStorage.setItem('id', response.data.id)
                localStorage.setItem('isAdmin', response.data.isAdmin)
                setIsAdmin(response.data.isAdmin);
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
                console.log(isAdmin)
                console.log(isLoggedIn)
                
               
        })
                
                .catch(function (response) { // Si erreur
                console.log(response);
                alert("Password incorrect ou email inexistant dans la base de données")
                });
                  
   

        } else { // si email ne respecte pas les regex définies
                alert("- Votre email n'est pas au bon format")
        }}



    return (
        
        <div className='login'>
            
        <img src={loginpic} alt='Groupomania' className='login__pic' />
        <h1>Connectez-vous</h1>
        <form className="login__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
                <input  
                        className="login__form__input" 
                        type="email" 
                        name="email" 
                        placeholder="Email" 
                        maxLength="40"
                        autoComplete="username" 
                        value={email} 
                        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        required 
                />

                <input   
                        className="login__form__input" 
                        type="password" 
                        name="password" 
                        maxLength="40"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        placeholder="Mot de passe" 
                        value={password} 
                        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        required
                />

                <input  className="login__form__button" 
                        type="submit" 
                        value="Je me connecte" 
                />
        </form>

        <p>C'est votre première visite ?</p>
        <p><Link to="/signup"><strong>Créez un compte</strong></Link></p>
    </div>
    );
  }

export default Login
```

Comment: The first warning means your component was removed from the dom long before your ajax response finished. We can't help you wit the second warning unless you post the code that generated the warning.

Comment: @AndyRay thanlks a lot, I edited my question with the useEffect try

Comment: Make sure the useEffect is in the body of the functional component at the top level & not inside a const. I am sure that is the problem.

Comment: Is `handleSubmit` tied to a button or something?  this component does not appear to render anything so I don't see how the `handleSubmit` is ever called.  If you're trying to run this every time this component is rendered, then the `useEffect` is the right thing - but be careful with that.  If the state changes history (which it does with the `.push`) and that causes a parent to change such that this component is no longer rendered, then you will likely get the warning you saw because you're trying to further update state on a component that is no longer in the DOM tree.

Comment: @mrrogers it is tied to a form <form className="login__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>. I tried to store isLoggedIn and isAdmin tu use it on other components... Thanks for your answer, it'sa  lot of new information but I will work on it :-)

Comment: @RajendranNadar Thanks ! the problem is when I do that, handleSubmit() in inside the useffect and I get  "Line 72:49:  'handleSubmit' is not defined" when submitiing my form

Comment: It will be great if you can add the repro in the https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: As others mentioned this is difficult to debug without knowing how the Login function is used and where/ how your state hooks are being used, right now this component isnt rendering anything and the state hooks arent being used

Comment: @t_killah thx. I've just added the rest of the code, I thought it would be simpler without the whole thing but it wasn't :-)

Comment: @RajendranNadar tnaks, done ! https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yundps?file=src/App.js

Comment: Hey no, you added the whole project just add the code where you have the issue. And display the error on stackblitz. It can only run client-side code, not server-side.

Comment: @RajendranNadar I tried but there is nothing displaying, I'll let you know if I get sthing, thanks a lot

Comment: @GeffSwayze this question will likely be closed. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (don't skip it, it's important) and [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking future questions, to help people understand your need and to get help faster.